# Texto placeholder do resumo da edição não aparece completo

Tags: suporte

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que poderíamos fazer nesse caso?

- Encurtar o texto?
- Colocar o texto completo como atributo `title` para aparecer quando o usuário colocar o ponteiro do mouse encima?
- Outro?

Answer (score 8):

Não gosto muito de usar o `title` por que ele é pouco visto. Melhor é encurtar o texto. Assim acho que não há nenhum significado perdido e não afeta como o sistema funciona (teria que por um tooltip em inglês também):

Original:

> **Editar resumo** <kbd>explique brevemente suas alterações (correções ortográficas, correções gramaticais, 
> formatação aperfeiçoada)</kbd>

Sugestão:

> **Resumo da edição** <kbd>explique brevemente suas alterações (ortografia, gramática, formatação, etc)</kbd>